# Image displacement

Tags: graphics

I'm trying to insert 4, in a 2 by 2 sort of matrix with this code

```
\begin{figure}[H] \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{figure/s0}
    \hspace{2mm}
    \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{figure/s1}
    \hfill
    \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{figure/s2}
    \hspace{2mm}
    \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{figure/s3}
    \hfill
\end{figure}
```

I made these images with Photoshop with dimension 400x250px. Why are not correctly aligned? Is it a code's problem? Because I checked with Photoshop and all of them have the same dimensions.

[image]

Comment: Because of `\hfill`. Replace it by `\\ `  or put the images in a `tabular`.

Comment: The unprotected end of lines might also add additional spaces, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines Can you make a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @marmot now works. Strange, I always used `\hfill` and I never saw this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has several unwanted spaces. It's better to do it like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]

\centering

\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{example-image}%
\hspace{2mm}%
\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}

\vspace{2mm}\vspace{-\lineskip}

\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}%
\hspace{2mm}%
\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{example-image-c}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Assuming you want 2mm between each image, horizontally and vertically, do two paragraphs and add the vertical space between them. A fix of `-\lineskip` is also needed. The fill at either side is already provided by `\centering`.

Note `%` in order not to add unwanted spaces.

[image]

What happens with your code?

Between the first two images you have a space of 2mm *plus* the normal interword space; this almost fills a line, so the first `\hfill` is discarded together with the interword space after the second image (due to the end-of-line). Because of `\centering`, the entire line is moved to the right margin.

The opposite happens in the second line, which is pushed to the left margin by the final centering glue.